# Need to grep and sort records based on 2 conditions

Tags: shell, sorting, grep

I have a requirement to grep and sort the records, first by mdmId (You can see it appearing after text mdmId is towards end of lines) and then by line number Or time-stamp (appearing in beginning of lines)

Current output :

```
$ grep -F -n -f grp_param cmxserver.log
43723:[2015-09-09 11:18:14,819] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything -  mdmId is : 834699
43896:[2015-09-09 11:18:16,085] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: Completed the beforeEverything -  mdmId is :
43900:[2015-09-09 11:18:16,086] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: *****CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave  **** -  mdmId is :
43902:[2015-09-09 11:18:16,086] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834699
45057:[2015-09-09 11:18:52,952] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything -  mdmId is : 834699
45247:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,067] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything -  mdmId is : 834947
45296:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,093] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: Completed the beforeEverything -  mdmId is :
45300:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,100] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: *****CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave  **** -  mdmId is :
45302:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,100] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834699
45623:[2015-09-09 11:18:55,603] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: Completed the beforeEverything -  mdmId is :
45627:[2015-09-09 11:18:55,605] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: *****CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave  **** -  mdmId is :
45629:[2015-09-09 11:18:55,605] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834947
45779:[2015-09-09 11:18:57,161] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834947
```

Desired output :

```
43896:[2015-09-09 11:18:16,085] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: Completed the beforeEverything -  mdmId is :
43900:[2015-09-09 11:18:16,086] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: *****CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave  **** -  mdmId is :
45296:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,093] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: Completed the beforeEverything -  mdmId is :
45300:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,100] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: *****CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave  **** -  mdmId is :
45623:[2015-09-09 11:18:55,603] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: Completed the beforeEverything -  mdmId is :
45627:[2015-09-09 11:18:55,605] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: *****CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave  **** -  mdmId is :
43723:[2015-09-09 11:18:14,819] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything -  mdmId is : 834699
43902:[2015-09-09 11:18:16,086] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834699
45057:[2015-09-09 11:18:52,952] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything -  mdmId is : 834699
45302:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,100] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834699
45247:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,067] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything -  mdmId is : 834947
45629:[2015-09-09 11:18:55,605] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834947
45779:[2015-09-09 11:18:57,161] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834947
```

You can see in Desired output, first record with mdmId null are picked and sorted as per line number (or time-stamp). Second is for Id 834699 and for Id 834947 in the end.

Your help is appreciated here.

Thanks

Comment: not all lines have mdmId value

Comment: Yes. Not all lines have mdmId value.

Answer (score 2):

Append this to your grep:

```
| awk '{$1=$NF" "$1; print}' | sort -k1,2n | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

Output:

```
43896:[2015-09-09 11:18:16,085] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: Completed the beforeEverything - mdmId is :
43900:[2015-09-09 11:18:16,086] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: *****CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave **** - mdmId is :
45296:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,093] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: Completed the beforeEverything - mdmId is :
45300:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,100] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: *****CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave **** - mdmId is :
45623:[2015-09-09 11:18:55,603] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: Completed the beforeEverything - mdmId is :
45627:[2015-09-09 11:18:55,605] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: *****CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave **** - mdmId is :
43723:[2015-09-09 11:18:14,819] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything - mdmId is : 834699
43902:[2015-09-09 11:18:16,086] [threadExecutor-8] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834699
45057:[2015-09-09 11:18:52,952] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything - mdmId is : 834699
45302:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,100] [threadExecutor-10] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834699
45247:[2015-09-09 11:18:54,067] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeEverything - mdmId is : 834947
45629:[2015-09-09 11:18:55,605] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834947
45779:[2015-09-09 11:18:57,161] [threadExecutor-1] [INFO ] com.delos: CustomerSaveHandler - beforeSave - beforeSave - CustomerRelationship - The mdmId is : 834947
```

See: [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: Nice! I didn't know this was called Schwartzian transform

Comment: Thanks Cyrus..Appreciated your help..It worked well..Let me experiment with it thanks